# Is there any reason to not use WinRAR or 7-Zip for zipping files?

Tags: zip

I was told to not use WinRAR or 7-Zip for putting files in a .zip archive. Do those two programs fully comply with the .zip specification when the zip format is selected, or is there some characteristic in the zip files they create that affects their compatibility, performance, or otherwise makes the result inferior to using other available zip programs?

Comment: Don't believe everything you hear.  Those are two of the most widely used archiving programs.  If there's a specific issue, you need to be specific.  In general, though, requesting software recommendations is off-topic.  You would want to phrase this around a specific issue you're trying to solve, like, "do winrar and 7zip have XYZ problem in creating a zip archive?"

Answer (score 0):

> I was told to not use winwar or 7zip for putting files in a .zip archive.

That's bollocks.

.zip <s>is originally</s> became popular from winzip who popularized the extension. That said WinRAR has its own .rar extension and 7zip has its own .7z compression extension. All of this programs can work whit .zip files and compressed them into such. 7zip is a mainstream compression program similar to winzip which was a hit back in 90" 00" - so just go ahead and use whatever you like, they are similar in compression and functionality.

Comment: Ouch, I just _have to_ correct this: ZIP files are not "originally from winzip", they are originally from PKZIP (back in 1989). Though arguably WinZip made ZIP more popular.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant :-D